# Add user control after page is loaded

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add dynamically a user control I created to an aspx page after it is loaded.
I tried sending an ajax request to a handler that used RenderControl function and sent back the control's html. I appended it to the DOM using javascript.

The problem is that some of the controls must go through their Page_Load function and that doesn't happen when using RenderControl function.

Does anyone have any idea how can I do that?

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you have to add it after the page is loaded? after the page is loaded, your in "client-world" (html,javasript). i cant envision a way to add a server control from the client. you'd need to do something really tricky/hacky (add a control to an updatepanel, then immediately fire off the trigger)

Comment: I am loading entire UI in the background and I don't want the client to feel this (this slows down the browser). I want the client to see part of the page and after this is done rendering, to continue and render the rest of the UI (after the page is loaded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
System.Web.UI.Page page = new System.Web.UI.Page();
CustomUserControl userControl = page.LoadControl("~/control.ascx") as CustomUserControl;
if (userControl == null)
{
//error
}

userControl.ArticleId = id;
//call any other properties or methods you need

page.Controls.Add(userControl);
System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute(page, sw, false);
responseString = sw.ToString();
```

hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you [load and add the user control dynamically to the page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972975.aspx#usercontrols_topic10)?

Comment: the page is already loaded, how can I turn to the server to add the controls dynamically (without pressing buttons or so)?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this that way.

Your controls don't go through their Page_Load, because they are not added to any control. All you are doing is rendering their html (using RenderControl) and loading it using javascript. There's no place for Page_Load event.

I would use UpdatePanel instead in that way:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlDynamic" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and then in code behind add your dynamic controls to panel

```
pnlDynamic.Controls.Add(new YourControl());
```